# Backendless Custom Event for Data aggregation

Tags: backendless

I am new to Backendless. I want to create a custom event to aggregate some data. I was only able to find one example for [Custom Event](http://JS-Code-Runner/examples/handlers/custom/average-stars.js).

The end goal is to get the most current review for each book of an author.

I have three tables: Authors, Books, and Reviews.

Is this the correct approach using java:

```
@BackendlessEvent( "Reviews" )
public class ReviewsEventHandler extends com.backendless.servercode.extension.CustomEventHandler
{

  @Async
  @Override
  public Map handleEvent( RunnerContext context, Map eventArgs )
  {
    // find reviews based on author
    StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
    whereClause.append( "Reviews.Books.Authors.Name = eventArgs" );

    // sort newest update on top
    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
    queryOptions.addSortByOption( "updateded DESC" );

    BackendlessDataQuery dataQuery = new BackendlessDataQuery();
    dataQuery.setQueryOptions( queryOptions );
    dataQuery.setWhereClause( whereClause.toString() );

    List<Reviews> reviews = Backendless.Persistence.of( Reviews.class ).find( dataQuery ).getCurrentPage();        

    return Reviews.emptyMap();
  }

}
```

Comment: I am updating the question

Answer (score 0):

Your "whereClause" does not make sense. You end up having this and that will not do anything - will result in the "invalid whereclause" error:

```
Authors[Books] Authors.Name = {result of toString() from eventArgs}
```

Comment: With a custom handler, what do I use to store the collection? do I get all of the related object?

Comment: To "store the collection" of what? Store where? Sorry, I didn't understand your question.